# sort fies by name using command feh

Tags: image

How to sort the display sequence of figures by modifying date when using feh?

I only know sort by name:

```
feh  adf* -S filename
```

The man page didn't specify that either. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy from `man feh`

```
-S, --sort sort_type
         The file list may be sorted according to image parameters.  
         Allowed sort types are: name, filename, mtime, width, height, 
         pixels, size, format.  For sort modes other than name, filename, 
         or mtime, a preload run will be
         necessary, causing a delay proportional to the number of images in the list.

         The mtime sort mode sorts images by most recently modified. To sort by 
         oldest first, reverse the filelist with --reverse.
```

Comment: i.e. `feh -S mtime` or `feh -S mtime --reverse`